# Why is there a java.lang.NullPointerException when referencing Image from a different class?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am creating a clone of Breakout for PC, earlier tonight I found that there was a NullPointerException being thrown and shown in the console. Oddly, the method `run()` is told to catch any exceptions that occour and show their stacktrace and then ignore them, but this time it freezes the game at the start, int the log, the keypresses are still tracked, but nothing happens in-game. Obviously, the game didn't abort, but will not repaint.

It seems to be coming from one line of code:

```
 if (by >= bricks[0].y && by <= bricks[0].y + bricks[0].img.getHeight(null) && bx >= bricks[0].x && bx <= bricks[0].x + bricks[0].img.getWidth(null)) {
```

Here is the log and stacktrace (the entire thing):

```
Game starting, menu boot.
Menu Loaded, JFrame visible.
Running thread.
Play clicked, start game initialization.
Creating JFrame.
JFrame created and visible.
Starting game thread
Initialize user variables.
Initialized user variables.
Initialization complete, start game.
java.lang.Execption in line 86/87, class Game. Stacktrace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Game.move(Game.java:195)
    at Game.run(Game.java:86)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Space hit!
Key ARROWLEFT hit.
Key ARROWLEFT hit.
Key ARROWLEFT hit.
Key ARROWLEFT hit.
Key ARROWLEFT hit.
Key ARROWLEFT hit.
Key ARROWLEFT hit.
Key ARROWLEFT released.
Key ESCAPE Hit!
```

I hope this problem can be solved.

Comment: Can you show more code? It's impossible to tell what's happening from that one line you posted.

Comment: We're not here to debug your code for you. If you can isolate it to that line, you can isolate it to a specific object used at that line. You've done 90% of the work; keep going.

Comment: Its foolish to write a line of code that long and complex!!  As you've discovered it's impossible to debug.

Comment: Hint:  Extract `bricks[0]` and save it in a temp, then rewrite your expression to use the temp.  You can then set a breakpoint on the if statement and check that the temp is non-null going into the if statement.

Comment: And it's not wise to catch and ignore exceptions.  It rarely works well to do that.

Comment: I can provide more code, just not tonight.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @MattBall I just solved the problem myself.

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at that "line":

```
   if (by >= bricks[0].y && 
       by <= bricks[0].y + bricks[0].img.getHeight(null) && 
       bx >= bricks[0].x && 
       bx <= bricks[0].x + bricks[0].img.getWidth(null)) {
```

Assuming that `bx`, `by`, and the `x` and `y` fields are all primitive types (e.g. `int`), then here's a list of things that *could* result in an NPE:

- the `bricks` variable is `null`
- the zeroth element of `bricks` is `null`
- the value of `bricks[0].img` is `null`

If `bx`, `by`, `x` and/or `y` is a wrapper type, then one of those could be `null`.  That would lead to an NPE when unboxing the value.

It is not caused by passing `null` to the `getHeight` or `getWidth` methods, because 1) I believe that is valid and 2) if it wasn't then the NPE would be thrown in a different place to what you stacktrace shows.

(I can't tell if passing `null` in those calls is *correct* ... but either way, it is not the cause of this NPE based on the evidence you have provided.)

---

If you want to figure what is *actually* causing the problem, debug the code or add some traceprints to *test* which of the things that could be `null` is actually `null`.

Comment: Nothing in the Bricks class that is referenced is null. I already verified that. All of the primitive types you mentioned ar public though, if that's what you mean by wrapper types.

Comment: No.  Thats not what I meant by wrapper types.  I meant non-primitive typed like `Integer` etcetera.  If you want more help, post an SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming that your brick[0].img is of the type java.awt.Image.  You are setting the ImageObserver to null in both the getHeight and the getWidth methods.  If you actually want the image displayed somewhere you need to put that thing as the ImageObserver.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html

The Button, Panel or the place you are trying to place the image should probably be passed in to the getWidth and the getHeight methods, because it most likely implements the ImageObserver Interface.

Comment: I already tried setting the ImageObserver to `this` as in the class Game, which calls the image.